# WSO2 - Identity server - Change password on first login

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

Is it possible using Identity server 6.1.0 to force the user to change his password on first login ?

I did not find anything in the documentation, but in this case should we use reset password feature to simulate this scenario?

Please guide me through the configuration in detail! Thank all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your usecase is aligning let the onboarded user set the password by himself first via an invitation link and log in to the application next, you can go with the approach that Sachin has mentioned.

If the usecase is the administrator onboards the user by setting a dummy password and not sending any email/invitation to reset the password, but expecting the user to change the password on first login, you can try the customization mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/77099434/10055162
IS-6.1.0 doesn't have this feature out of the box.

Comment: Thank you <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3

Answer (score 0):

Can use Identity Server Invite new users flow

Here the user on-boarding flows initiated by administrators from an invitation to the user's email which allow respective end users to decide their own passwords or verify the accounts created by administrators.

https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/guides/identity-lifecycles/invitation-workflow/#set-up-notifications

Comment: Thank you <3  <3  <3  <3  <3  <3  <3  <3